# Handling access violation in applications

Tags: c++, exception

My x64 application is compiled with /EHa,

I want to guard my code against access violations, but the application process seems to crash regardless of my SEH and termination handlers.

```
void my_se_translator(unsigned int, struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS*) {
    cout << "se_translator_called" << endl;
}

void my_terminate_handler() {
    cout << "my_terminate_handler_called" << endl;
}

#pragma optimize("", off)
void test() {

    int* k = nullptr;
    int z = *k;
}
#pragma optimize("", on)

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    _set_se_translator(my_se_translator);
    set_terminate(my_terminate_handler);

    test();

    return 0;
}
```

Would appreciate a good explanation for why _set_se_translator does not work in this case?

Comment: On which operating system? With which compiler?

Comment: OS: Windows, Compiler: MSVC.

Comment: `_set_se_translator` is for setting a function to translate Win32 exceptions to C++ exceptions. Maybe the behavior is getting optimized out because you have no C++ exception handling in your code. You might be better served by just using `__try/__except` to catch the Win32 exceptions directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z4bw5h5.aspx):

> Your translator function should do no more than throw a C++ typed
>   exception. If it does anything in addition to throwing (such as
>   writing to a log file, for example) your program might not behave as
>   expected, because the number of times the translator function is
>   invoked is platform-dependent.

when you add a simple exception class:

```
class myException{
};
```

Then throw the exception in the my_se_translator function, and catch the exception in either the main or test function your example should work.

```
void my_se_translator(unsigned int, struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS*) {
    std::cout << "se_translator_called" << std::endl;
    throw myException();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {


    _set_se_translator(my_se_translator);
    set_terminate(my_terminate_handler);
    try{
        test();
    }
    catch(myException e) {
        std::cout << "EXCEPTION!" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's pretty strange that Microsoft did such a thing, what if I wanted to signal application shutdown events to all of my threads in my _se_translator and try exit the process in my own way, they don't quite allow that.

Comment: You could still implement this in the catch(){}